# Unable to run transformed jsx to js file in browser. Asking for in browser jsxtransformer

Tags: reactjs, browserify, reactify

I am trying to use reactify for jsx transformation and I have done the transformation from jsx to regular js using reactify. But when I try to run my transformed js file, it's somehow not showing the content. But when I import in browser jsxtransformer then it's showing the content. I am not able to understand the error in my procedure. If someone knows about it, please help me.
Thank You..

Comment: Please provide some code. Maybe you are referencing the original unproccessed jsx file in your HTML markup?

Comment: Not actually.. My unprocessed and processed jsx are in different folders. So, I am sure that I am referring processed jsx code..

Comment: You'll need to show us some code and your command lines if you want a helpfull answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation states](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/), in-browser transpiling has been removed from Babel, however Daniel15 has created a standalone build for use in "non-Node.js environments including browsers" here:

https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone

All you need to do is add this reference to your page:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>`

And then make sure you're using the `type="text/babel"` attribute in your references to other script files, for example:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/myReactComponent.jsx"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But I actually did silly mistake. While importing my transformed javascript, I used type="text/jsx" that's why it was giving me a problem. But after replacing it with type="text/javascript", it is running properly.